# Font Awesome Issue

Tags: java, android, font-awesome

I am trying to use fontawesome in my project but there is a problem with plane icons! they are shown as a square! for example :
for using "telegram-plane" from [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) I add the below code to my strings:

```
<string name="fa_telegram_plane">&#xf3fe;</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<string name="fa_telegram_plane">\uf3fe</string>
```

Instead of this:

```
<string name="fa_telegram_plane">&#xf3fe;</string>
```

**EDIT:**

May be that that icon is only in the **PRO** release, and therefore unavailable in the **FREE** version.

But [this one](https://fontawesome.com/icons/paper-plane?style=solid) is quite similar, isn't it? **`\uf1d8`**

Comment: still not working ! I m not sure but it might be a problem with font awesome itself?

Comment: It could. I use font-awesome with the "Unicode" format and it works pretty well. But I'm using different icons. Maybe try to change font-awesome release. An older version might work fine. Or it's simply in the "PRO" release, therefore you can't have it in the FREE version. But [this](https://fontawesome.com/icons/paper-plane?style=solid) is quite similar, isn't it? **`\uf1d8`**

Comment: though I was using pro it wasnt working, this last one works pretty great . Thanks a lot

Comment: @statosdotcom Glad to help.